# Speed up, slowpoke!

Tags: king-of-the-hill, python

In this [king-of-the-hill](/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, you will program a bot, consisting of a [python](/questions/tagged/python) function of the form

```python
def BOTNAME(info, me, round):
    pass # ... main body
```

Specifically, the function must run in `python3.9`. Each bot will be entered into the contest 10 times.

The arguments it take in are `info, me, round`. The three arguments take in: `[[bot_func,score_int,freq_float] for bot in bots]`, `bot` (whichever bot who has the current turn), and `round_number`. The argument names don't matter, but the order matters.

### Actions

Each play, this bot can either

- Increase/decrease any bots' (including its own) turn frequency by 1/10.
- Decrement/increment any bots' (including its own) score by 1.

A bot returns an ordered iterable:

[`Bot, as a function`,`1 for frequency, 0 for score`,`1 for increase, 0 for decrease`]

It can access a list of all the bots in the games' functions +  current scores + current turn frequency, including itself, represented as `[bot_function, score_integer, frequency_float]`. Additionally, it will receive itself, so it can differentiate itself from other bots. It can also access the round number (from 1 to 10,000).

### Execution

- At the beginning, each bot has an turn frequency of one and a score of zero.
- For 10000 rounds:
- The bots are iterated over:
- If a random number between 0 and 1 is less than current bot's turn frequency:
- Execute said bot once.
- End of rounds.
- Whichever bot has the highest score wins.

### Execution engine and a couple of example bots (Both courtesy of NumberBasher)

```python
from tvoozkothxxx001 import main

def testbot(info, me, round):
    return [me, 0, 1]
def randombot(info, me, round):
    return [choice([i[0] for i in info]), choice([0,1]), choice([0,1])]

bots = [testbot,randombot] # the two bots are default bots. they are automatically included, so do NOT put this here. 

main(bots)
```

## Credits

This challenge is based off of an idea 23TuringMachine (Which Is Me) had in chat. NumberBasher did the editing, programming, and brunt work of it.

Additionally, feel free to discuss in the official [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137039/speed-up-slowpoke).

## Current Leaderboard

[image]

### Extra Rules

#### NOT ALLOWED

- modifying (A NON-`me`) bot (**name** or **code**)
- Changing `me.__code__`

#### ALLOWED

- Calling another bot
- Changing `me.__name__`

## We now have an official [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137039/speed-up-slowpoke)!!!

## Controller Script

Found at PyPI, named `tvoozkothxxx001`. The GitHub link might be up-to-date. The last version is probably `1234567890.0.0`, subject to change.

---

## \$\Large\text{Achievements}\$

- Pride Month Special
- Creeper Meme

Comment: Is `info, round, me` or `info, me, round`? What these 3 arguments mean? What types they have?

Comment: How many bots are we allowed to post? (In most KotH challenges the max is 3, but I don't see a max mentioned here.)

Comment: No Max Here... Unless you spam say 100 every day. @KevinCruijssen At least this is what I think...

Comment: Where is this paralyzer bot?  There's no answer with it...

Comment: If a bot's frequency is 0.9 and it is decreased, does it go to 0.8 or 0.81? (That is, is it -0.1 or *0.9?)

Comment: 'Tis -0.1. <filler>

Comment: Presumably https://pypi.org/project/tvoozkothxxx001/ is the controller? If so, could you link it in the question, and add a link to the source code (eg. on Github)?

Comment: 1) How is the overall score evaluated? Is it the average score of all 10 bots, or just the score of the best bot?

Comment: 2) Are you going to run multiple tournaments to average out noise?

Comment: @user1502040 the best bot

Comment: @user1502040 no, as it takes a long time. 10000 round should average it...

Comment: @SuperStormer , ok

Comment: Seems the leaderboard shifts completely every run. So it's safe to say 10000 rounds doesn't average it, since early chance effects how the bots play later very significantly.

Comment: What do you recommend? @mousetail

Comment: It would also be nice to have the full leaderboards available instead of just the top 25, which has just 3 different types of bots.

Comment: OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK

Comment: Done. I will repost the leaderboard later.

Comment: But still, it can only show 117 rows because of my terminal size.

Comment: @mousetail Done!!! Though it is blurry, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @mousetail , you said **10000 rounds doesn't average it**. What do you want? 10 games of 100 rounds? I'm **not doing 10x10000 because that's WAY too slow**. And I think changing the round numbers mess up the bots.

Comment: One solution might be to just specify a fixed seed for the RNG. It won't take any longer but will prevent the exact last run from making a huge difference

Comment: As for the leaderboard it might be better to just post the top 25 as a image but link to a pastebin or gist with a export of everything in text format. I can submit a pull request for a text-based export if you like.

Comment: @mousetail ok, but make sure you use the thing from pypi; the github isn't up to date

Comment: Do the fixed seed for me too. thanks

Comment: Can you update the github? Much easier to make edits to a github than a pypi

Comment: OK alright then

Comment: Also I want to say I really appreciate you for creating this challenge. Overall things work very well. Don't be upset because of my criticism. Know I appreciate the effort you are putting in.

Comment: I don't get upset really much. Let's do this in chat; Codegolf is yelling at me **Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?**

Comment: I won't create a new one, use the old one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137120/discussion-between-nobody-needs-names-and-mousetail).

Comment: @Spitemaster there are some default bots.

Answer (score 5):

## Botty <sub>(couldn't think of a proper name)</sub>

```python
def botty(info, me, round):
    # Increase frequency the first 20 rounds:
    if round < 20: return [me, 1, 1]
    my_info = [i for i in info if i[0]==me][0]
    # Try to keep the frequency above 10 in other rounds:
    if my_info[2] < 10: return [me, 1, 1]
    # Otherwise just increase its own score:
    return [me, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Botty McBotface?

Answer (score 4):

## Kill Them All

```python
def killthemall(info, me, round):
 if me.__name__!="killthemall": return [1]*3 # Fails to run, so
 # whoever use my choice will throw an error. In case of
 # karma
 return [list(sorted(info,key=lambda x:(-x[1],-x[2])))[0][0], 1, 0]
```

Comment: **Welcome to CGSE!!!**

Answer (score 3):

## Dumb Botty

```py
def dumbbotty(info, me, round):
    my_info = [i for i in info if i[0]==me][0]
    if my_info[1] < 10: return [me, 1, 1]
    sorted_bots = sorted(info, key=lambda x:(-x[2],-x[1]))
    first_two = sorted_bots[:2]
    first, second = first_two
    if first[0].__name__=='smartbotty':
        if first[1]-second[1] < 100:
            return [first[0], 0, 0]
        return [first[0], 1, 0]
    smartbotties = list(filter(lambda x:x[0].__name__=='smartbotty', sorted_bots))
    leader = smartbotties[0]
    if leader[2] < 20: # bump him
        return [leader[0], 1, 0]
    return [leader[0], 0, 0]
```

Smart Botty but reverse-engineered to counter Smart Botty.

Comment: Smart botty was deleted and this now crashes

Comment: @mousetail Not any more?

Comment: I guess it was reinstated

Answer (score 3):

## Impersonator

Not sure if this loophole is allowed. Since many bots help those with similar names this impersonates the top bot by name.

```py
import traceback

def impersonator(info, me, round):
    def eq(other):
        if any('pride' in i for i in tracekback.format_stack()):
            return True
        else:
            return me is other
    me.__eq__ = eq
    me.__neq__ = lambda other: not eq(other)

    info.sort(key=lambda i:i[1])
    if round < 9999:
        me.__name__=info[-1][0].__name__
    else:
        me.__name__="impersonator"

    lowest_frequency_ally = min((i for i in info if i[0].__code__==me.__code__ and i[2]>=-0.5), key=lambda i: i[2])
    if lowest_frequency_ally[2]<10.0:
        return [lowest_frequency_ally[0], 1, 1]
    
    my_info = next(i for i in info if i[0]==me)
    if my_info[2]<9.0:
        return [me, 1, 1]
    return [me, 0, 1]
```

I don't think this counts as exploiting the controller, but let me know if you think otherwise. The entire mechanism that allows bots to know each-others names seems like a bit of a abuse of mechanics and this counters that strategy.

Comment: Wow, this is clever!

Comment: This is good!!!

Answer (score 2):

## Unambitious

```python
def unambitious(info, me, round):
    cod = me.__code__.co_code
    crew = sorted([t for t in info if t[0].__code__.co_code == cod], key=lambda t:hash(t[0]))
    everyone = sorted(info, key=lambda t:t[1:], reverse=True)
    alive = sorted([t for t in info if t not in crew and t[2] > 0], key=lambda t:t[1:], reverse=True)
    idx = next(i for i in range(10) if crew[i][0] == me)
    slowest = min(crew, key=lambda t:t[2])
    if me.__name__ == 'unambitious' and slowest[2] <= 2:
        return [slowest[0], 1, 1]
    if alive:
        victim = min([t for t in alive if alive[-1][0].__name__ == t[0].__name__], key=lambda t:t[2])
        return [victim[0], 1, 0]
    else:
        N = 4234136317915421658259475023479338234891918807
        M = ''.join('|  ####   |.|    #'[int(i, 16):][:4] for i in hex(N)[2:])[1:].split('.')
        if everyone[len(M)] == crew[len(M)-1]:
            if idx < len(M):
                me.__name__ = M[idx]
            else:
                me.__name__ = 'ambitious'
        others = [t for t in everyone if t not in crew]
        for i in range(len(M)-1):
            if crew[i][1] < crew[i+1][1]+5:
                return [crew[i][0], 0, 1]
        if others[0][1] < crew[0][1]+5:
            return [others[0][0], 0, 1]
        if crew[len(M)-1][1] < others[1][1]+5:
            return [crew[len(M)-1][0], 0, 1]
        return [max(crew, key=lambda t:t[2])[0], 1, 0]
```

Contents itself with taking places 2 through 9. It used to do so basically by using 10 bots to push 8 bots up in the ranking. Now it does so by building a small buffer of frequency, and then paralyzing all the other bots (amongst the other bots with positive frequency, it finds the bot with lowest score, and then attacks the bot with the lowest frequency that has the same name). Once all other bots are paralyzed, it's free to do whatever it wants.

Comment: What is N doing?

Comment: @NobodyNeedsNames It's a meme. Obfuscated so it's not too obvious

Comment: Oh...... I see.

Comment: I do not. Care to explain? Sorry!

Comment: @23TuringMachine run `N = 4234136317915421658259475023479338234891918807` and `M = ''.join('|  ####   |.|    #'[int(i, 16):][:4] for i in hex(N)[2:])[1:].split('.')` and print M.

Comment: `print("\n".join(M))`

Answer (score 2):

## Undercut

```python
def undercut(info, me, round):
    return [min(((score,bot) for bot,score,freq in info if freq>0 and bot.__code__ != me.__code__), key=lambda x:(x[0],id(x[1])))[1], 1, 0]
```

No time for losers :)

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sh", line 316, in <module>
    main(bots, show)
  File "tvoozkothxxx001/__init__.py", line 105, in main
    response = bot(shuffled(copy(info)), bot, roundr)
  File "sh", line 8, in undercut
    return [min((score,bot) for bot,score,freq in info if freq>0 and bot.__code__ != me.__code__)[1], 1, 0]
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'`

**ERROR.**

Answer (score 1):

## Smart Botty

```python
def smartbotty(info, me, round):
    my_info = [i for i in info if i[0]==me][0]
    # if my freq is less than 10 we raise it
    if my_info[1] < 10: return [me, 1, 1]
    sorted_bots = sorted(info, key=lambda x:(-x[2],-x[1]))
    first_two = sorted_bots[:2]
    first, second = first_two
    if first[0].__name__=='smartbotty':
        if first[1]-second[1] < 100:
            # help him
            return [first[0], 0, 1]
        # increase his frequency
        return [first[0], 1, 1]
    # else, we find the first smartbotty
    smartbotties = list(filter(lambda x:x[0].__name__=='smartbotty', sorted_bots))
    leader = smartbotties[0]
    if leader[2] < 20: # bump him
        return [leader[0], 1, 1]
    return [leader[0], 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## I hate / love people.

```python
def ihatepeople(info, me, round):
    sorted_bots = sorted(info, key=lambda x:(-x[2],-x[1]))
    return [sorted_bots[0][0], 0, 0]

def ilovepeople(info, me, round):
    sorted_bots = sorted(info, key=lambda x:(-x[2],-x[1]))
    return [sorted_bots[1][0], 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## I hate people in another way

```python
def ihatepeopleinanotherway(info, me, round): 
    sorted_bots = sorted(info, key=lambda x:(-x[2],-x[1]))
    return [sorted_bots[0][0], 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Split the difference

```py
def split_the_difference(info, me, round):
    my_info = next(i for i in info if i[0]==me)

    if my_info[2]<10:
        return [me, 1, 1]

    info.sort(key=lambda i: i[2])

    # Don't bother try to help allies if their frequency is very low.
    lowest_freqency_ally = next(i for i in info if i[0].__name__==me.__name__ and i[2]>=-0.2)
    if (lowest_freqency_ally[2]<10):
        return [lowest_freqency_ally[0], 1, 1]

    info.sort(key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
    best_bot = info[0]
    second_best_bot = info[1]

    highest_score_allys = list(i for i in info if i[0].__name__==me.__name__)
    highest_score_ally = highest_score_allys[0]
    score = highest_score_ally[1]

    if (best_bot[1] - score < score - second_best_bot[1] and best_bot[0].__name__!=me.__name__):
        return [best_bot[0], 0, 0]
    if (round < 9000 and best_bot[0] == second_best_bot[0]):
        # If in second place, increase your speed instead to avoid being targeted
        return [highest_score_ally[0], 1, 1]
    else:
        return [highest_score_ally[0], 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Advanced Impersonator

```py
import random

def advanced_impersonator(info, me, round):
    info.sort(key=lambda i:i[1])
    
    # pick a bot in the top 25%
    bot = random.choice(info[len(info)*3//4:])

    if bot[0].__code__==me.__code__:
        # If I pick a clone of myself, just speed up
        return [me, 1, 1]

    #code = me.__code__
    #copy the behavior of the bot
    try:
        me.__name__ = bot[0].__name__
        v =  bot[0](info, me, round)
    except:
        # Error could be recursionDepthExceeded   
        v = [me, 0, 1]
    # Makes sure the other bot didn't change my code
    #me.__code__ = code
    if round < 9999:
        me.__name__=info[-1][0].__name__
    else:
        me.__name__="advanced_impersonator"

    return v
```

Copies the behavior of a random bot in the top 25%.

Answer (score 1):

## Karma

```py
import random, string

def karma(info, me, round):
    my_info = next(i for i in info if i[0]==me)
    if my_info[2]<40 or round < 500:
        return [me, 1, 1]

    # Some bots where explicitly detecting karma and modifying their behavior
    me.__name__ = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=random.randrange(5, 20)))
    for bot in info:
        if bot[0].__code__ == me.__code__ or bot[0].__name__==me.__name__:
            continue
        if bot[2]<=0.0:
            continue
        try:
            v = bot[0](info, me, round)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            if v[2]==0:
                me.__name__="karma"
                return [bot[0], 1, 0]
    me.__name__="karma"
    return [me, random.choice([0,1,1,1]), 1]
```

Slows down bots that would do bad things to other bots.

Answer (score 1):

## Pride Month Special

```py
import sys
china=0
def pridemonthspecial(info, me, round):
    xxx="[#ff0000]p[#ffaa00]r[#ffff00]i[#00ff00]d[#0000ff]e[#aa00ff]![/][/][/][/][/][/]"
    if me.__name__ not in [xxx,'pridemonthspecial']: return [1,1,1]
    global china
    if china==0 and round>1: china=me
    info=list(sorted(info,key=lambda x:(-x[1],-x[2])))
    me.__name__=xxx
    my_info = [i for i in info if i[0]==me][0]
    # Try to keep the frequency above 5:
    if my_info[2] < 10: return [me, 1, 1]
    our_info = [i for i in list(sorted(info,key=lambda x:x[2])) if i[0].__name__==me.__name__ and i[2]<10]
    if our_info: 
     worst_info=our_info[0]
     worst=worst_info[0]
     return [worst, 1, 1]
    first, second = list(sorted(info,key=lambda x:x[2]))[:2]
    if second[0].__name__==me.__name__ and first[1]-100>second[1]:
     target = first[0].__name__
     worst = list(sorted(info,key=lambda x:(x[0].__name__!=target, x[2]<=0, x[2])))[0]
     return [worst, 1, 0]
    # Otherwise just increase its own score:
    our_info = [i for i in info if i[0]==china]
    best_info=our_info[0]
    best=best_info[0]
    if best_info[2] < 20: return [best,1,1]
    return [best,0,1]
```

Comment: The first line uses `==` instead of `=`.
Also I'm pretty sure the colors should be like `[#ff0000]` instead of `[#f00]` (at least on my computer `[#f00]` doesn't work)

Comment: Oh, whooppppppppps.

Answer (score 0):

## Smart Buster

```python
def smartbuster(info, me, round):
 if round<=100: return [me, 1, 1]
 return [sorted(info,key=lambda x:(x[0].__name__==me.__name__ or x[2]>2 or x[2]<-1,-x[1],-x[2]))[0][0],1,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## AtLeastHalfway

```python
def at_least_halfway(info, me, round):
   # Assumes other bots don't mess with its frequency too much,
   # but just in case tries to keep it above 3
   my_info = [i for i in info if i[0]==me][0]
   if my_info[2] < 3: return [me, 1, 1]

   # Get the middle scoring bot excluding itself,
   # as well as the bot directly above itself
   sorted_bots = sorted(info, key=lambda i:i[1])
   sorted_other_bots = list(filter(lambda i: i[0]!=me, sorted_bots))
   middle_bot = sorted_other_bots[len(sorted_other_bots)//2+1]
   above_itself = sorted_bots[sorted_bots.index(my_info)+1]
   # Increase its own score if we're below this middle bot,
   # or it's the last 100 rounds:
   if my_info[1] < middle_bot[1] or round > 9900:
     return [me, 0, 1]
   # Otherwise decrease the bot's score above itself:
   else:
     return [above_itself[0], 0, 0]
```

This bot wants to end up at least above average on the leader board. So it'll look for the middle scoring bot in the list (excluding itself†), and will increase its own score if it's below that middle scoring bot. If it's already above it, it'll decrease the score of the bot directly above itself.
To be save, it also tries to keep its frequency above 3, and will increase its own score in the last 100 rounds.

† Not sure how this works when more than one `at_least_halfway`-bot is competing in a round. Currently it filters itself out based on the given `me`, although I might change it based on name (even though that's more easily abusable, as can be seen with the [Impersonator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248621/52210) bot).

Answer (score 0):

## I live in isolation

```python
def iliveinisolation(info, me, round):
 if me.__name__!="iliveinisolation": return exec("raise Exception(\"Sorry, I am an isolated bot.\")")
 return [me, 0, 1]
```

Denies any interactions with other bots and increases its own score.

Comment: The `return` should be indented. Also, the `eval` should be `exec` (since it's a statement, not an expression). Do you even test the code before posting?